# Typescript function extension is broken

Tags: typescript, function, extends

Typescript 3.9.4:

```
type Test = ((value: { a: number }) => any) extends ((value: { [key: string]: any }) => any) ? true : false;
```

Expected type for Test is true since `{a: number}` does `extends` `{[key: string]: any}`.

The actual type for Test is false which I don't really understand. Are there any ways to make this sort of situation work?

Comment: What's the background behind this code? Did you write it or did you see it somewhere? What version of TypeScript are you using?

Comment: When I put this in typescript on my machine `Test` is true. What version of typescript are you using?

Comment: @MikeJerred on [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=48&pln=1&pc=109#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oAo0DcCGAbArhAFxQDeU2JAdvgLYBGEATlAL4CUKAfBVSJxAAewCFQAm8dFjyES5ANoBrCCBKImASyoBzALolsfNp2Q9D-KAH4owJoSgkAZnngQA3EA), it shows as `false`. (v3.9.2 down to v2.8.1, beyond that it starts parsing it as a function type)

Comment: @Dai I was trying to do polymorphism on function but it doesn't work out because of this error. It kept saying "property value is required".

Comment: @MikeJerred I'm using version 3.9.4. Sorry, I already edited the post to add the version in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type doesn't extend the other one.

We can see that `{ a: number }` **does** extend `{ [key: string]: number }` by imagining calling a function with a signature like this:

```js
foo(arg: { [key: string]: number })
```

It would be valid to supply an argument of type `{ a: number }`. Anything `foo` does with it's argument would be valid to do with something of type `{ a: number }` too.

However if you have:

```js
foo(arg: (value: { [key: string]: number }) => any)
```

It would not be valid to supply an argument of type `(value: { a: number }) => any` because the argument for `foo` needs a function that is capable of accepting an object with any string keys. Imagine if `foo` was implemented like this:

```js
foo(arg: (value: { [key: string]: number }) => any) {
  arg({ b: 7 });
}
```

This code would not be valid if `arg` has type `(value: { a: number }) => any`.

For further reading, the concept we are dealing with here is called *type contravariance*.

Comment: Isn't `A extends B` about if anything that fits A will fit B? I think what you are saying is if anything that fits B will fit A.

Comment: @tranphananhkhoa No, `A extends B` (or rather: `Derived extends Base` means that anything that can *receive* `Base`  can receive `Derived`- but anything that accepts a `Derived` cannot accept a `Base` (because a `Base` is not a valid `Derived` value). Note that that only applies to immediate values (i.e. `Base` and `Derived`) - things get complicated when we're involving in-and-out type parameters, e.g. `List<Base>` and `List<Derived>`, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)

Comment: @Dai hmm yea, I used my words incorrectly there. However, in this case, if function `foo` works with `(value: {[key: string]: any}) => any`, `foo` will also works with `(value: {a: number}) => any`. So in your word it should be if `foo` receives `(value: {[key: string]: any}) => any`, `foo` recieves `(value: {a: number}) => any`. So `Test` should be `true` right.

Comment: @Dai Yea, you are right. It is a bit complicated there. It should be false.

Comment: @Dai Hmm, actually no, I think `Test` should still be `true`. The example given by @Mike is not the case because what @Mike was doing is to invalidate this statement `B extends A` and `C extends A` then `B extends C`.

Comment: @tranphananhkhoa But `( B extends C ) === false`.

Comment: @Dai yes, I agree it is obviously false but my case is about `B extends A`. What I meant was that @Mike introduced a new type `C` which is `(arg: (value: { [key: string]: number }) => any`. So when he concludes `(B extends C) === false`, it is totally correct but I'm asking about `(B extends A)`.

Comment: Some types, such as a list, are covarient - i.e. `List<P>` is wider than `List<Q>` if `P` is wider than `Q` (and vice versa). However some types are contravarient - and a function is an example of this - so if `P` is wider than `Q` then `Func<Q>` is wider than `Func<P>`.

Comment: @MikeJerred I think I got it now. Thank you.